# Is it possible to get the transfer function of something like this?: $\text{Out}= \text{In}\cdot \frac {p_1(s)}{q_1(s)}+k\cdot \frac {p_2(s)}{q_2(s)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I was solving an electronic circuit for work, and while trying to obtain the transfer function of the circuit, I encounter something like this:

$$V_\text{out}(s) = V_\text{in}(s) \cdot \frac{p_1(s)}{q_1(s)} + (5V)\cdot \frac{p_2(s)}{q_2(s)}$$

where $V_\text{out}$ is the output voltage; $V_\text{in}$ is the input voltage; $5V$ is a constant ($5$ volts); $p_1(s)$, $p_2(s)$, $q_1(s)$ and $q_2(s)$ are polynomials of the form $a_n s^n + a_{n-1} s^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 s + a_0$.

I wanted to get $ \dfrac {V_\text{out}(s)}{V_\text{in}(s)}$, but I think that those $5V$ are another input, not allowing me to get the transfer function. I remember reading that because of this there are other methods of analysis, or the other inputs are not consider in the analysis, but I preferred to reach out here to clarify this.

Edited: Because of LaTeX formatting.